# Eclipse installation error after everything

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have downloaded the android sdk and java se runtime env. Also but when I am opening eclipse it is showing that "A java runtime environment or Java development kit must be available to run eclipse......" what to do to fix it?

Comment: "A java runtime environment or Java development kit must be available to run eclipse......" means you do not have java installed on your pc. Install it!

Answer (score 0):

please install jdk from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html and than install android setup with eclipse

please follow

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-installation/

Answer (score 0):

You must have installed JRE or JDK on your machine.I kindly suggest that you perform install JDK (there are dozens reasons for that).

Entire installation process is described here for [SunJDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/index-137561.html) or here for [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/install/).
Pay attention to setup of environment variables.

After this you will have correct working environment.

**EDIT 1: In order to show env setup and some clarification to user I am updated answer:**

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 and my environment variables related to Java are set like this:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_45
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
JRE_HOME=/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_45
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
```

Note that JDK is installed in `/usr/local/java` folder and you should to change this path regarding to your installation.

If you are using MS Windows, you have to set environment variables in System properties

> Control panel -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment
>   variables

adding all as described above (with your paths of course).

Note: Don't forget to add JRE or JDK  in PATH (analyze my setup)!

Comment: i have installed java jdk, still having this prob.

Comment: Are your installed JDK / JRE is used by eclipse? Check this in eclipse (Preferences -> Java -> Installed JRE).

Comment: no way to check -_- when i click on that eclipse.exe it is showing "A java run time environment(jre) or jdk must be available in order to run Eclipse. no java virtual machine was found after searching the following location.......in your Current PATH

Comment: In installation procedure is described how to set environment variables. Look this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: Did you finally perform all install tasks? Are you need some clarification? I can paste my env setups if you need that.

Comment: if i am dragging javaw.exe in eclipse.exe then only eclipse is oppening or else not.. how to fix it? i have copied bin folder and pasted on jre after creating a new folder. and when i click to open eclipse again, nothing happens -_-

Comment: You have not drag (or move) your executing files. Instead of this, you have to setup all environment variables which tell to your system where is Java, or eclipse or something else. When your env variables are set properly, eclipse will use your JDK (or JRE) and then will start without problems. I will edit my answer and I will add my env variables related to JDK. You can edit your settings regardning to my setup. I think that will resolve all your problems.

Answer (score -1):

You have to set the JAVA_HOME variable in your system after installing Java on the machine pointing to the folder where Java is installed before starting Eclipse.

Comment: To set environment variables - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html. Same way you can also add variable named JAVA_HOME and value is location where JDK is installed.